# Understanding Schoenfeld Residuals

Tags: self-study, survival, schoenfeld-residuals

I'm reading the original paper by [Schoenfeld from 1982](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2335876). It is very laconic.

Few parts that I don't understand:
[image]

Why can we substitute $\hat \beta - \beta$ with the Score, and why is the score equal to $U^{-1} \sum r_k$ ?

It continues:
[image]

Here I don't understand anything. He doesn't even define $\delta_{ij}$ (though I'm assuming it's the Kronecker delta).

Finally:
[image]

Why does the expected value of the (observed) residual is approximately 0? How can this be shown?

And how does expanding $\mathbb E[X_{ik}|R_i]$ we arrive at the expected value of the residual? $\mathbb E[X_{ik}|R_i]$ is defined to be:
[image]